# Implicits, pimpl pattern etc

Tags: scala

Let's say that I have these classes:

```
case class A()
case class B()
case class C(a: A, b: B)
```

and these variables:

```
val a = A()
val b = B()
```

Is there a way to get an instance of `C` implicitly and without making `a` and `b` implicit vals? I.e. if I have a method expecting a `C`:

```
def foo(c: C)
```

Comment: "Pimpl" is a C++ism - it means "pointer to implementation" and is a way to avoid exposing class implementation details in headers, primarily to improve compilation speed.  You may have meant "pimp my library" which is a Scalaism and means "use implicits to add stuff to a library when you can't modify the source."

Answer (score 6):

The `case class A` notation was deprecated. You have to use `case class A()`, otherwise assigning `A` to the `val a` will result in `a` referring to the companion object of the case class `A` which is generated behind the scene.

It's my understanding you wanted `a` to refer to the instance of the case class, not the companion object.

If so, what you're asking is possible - `a` and `b` don't have to be implicit, but you do have to add a new implicit method into the scope:

```
implicit def obtainC = new C(a, b)
```

Then, you have to put the `implicit` modifier to `c` in the method `foo`:

```
def foo(implicit c: C)
```

Complete session:

```
scala> case class A()
defined class A

scala> case class B()
defined class B

scala> case class C(a: A, b: B)
defined class C

scala> val a = A()
a: A = A()

scala> val b = B()
b: B = B()

scala> implicit def obtainC = new C(a, b)
obtainC: C

scala> def foo(implicit c: C) = {}
foo: (implicit c: C)Unit

scala> foo
```

Comment: Thanks! I know about that issue regarding the syntax for case classes. I was just to lazy to print them out correctly. My bad ;)

Comment: No problem. I just pointed it out because I wasn't sure whether you maybe wanted `a` and `b` to really point to companion objects. :)

Comment: On the case class A() point, if the object has no data, it's actually a good candidate to be case object A (analogous to Nil for the empty list). Making it a case object still gives you equals, hashCode, and toString and keeps A "uniform" when it's part of other case classes.

Comment: What I really would like to do is put all this in an object which I can import (i.e. the implicit defs). The example above work since val a and b is known in obtainC. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do that if `a` and `b` are visible in the object you put the implicit into. Additionally, if you put this implicit `obtainC` in the companion class of `C`, you will not have to import it, as it's then in the implicit scope of `C`.